# How to Connect Existing Jenkins server to New EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops

I am trying to connect my new EC2 instance to existing jenkins master server, I have installed java and set path as well but still I am not able to connect to master jenkins server.Please help me with the issue I am facing. Your help is really appriciate.

Comment: Have you allowed the new EC2 instance in your Security Group?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some basic ways to troubleshoot this issue:

- On EC2 VM:

  - Verify status of SSH service. Is port 22 listening?
  - Double-check the Security Group.
- On Jenkin:

  - Verify that you added the correct authentication key for Agent server.